# how does self in a child class exactly work in php

Tags: php

I am trying to generate an xml file using the below class, when an array data is passed with no depth constraints the xml gets generated by the below code successfully. I am just trying to figure out as how  `self::createNode($value, $child);` statements works does it create a new object? what is the significance of the the `parent::_construct` statement in the class constructor ? as the encoding is initialized already in the child class constructor.
What I have read since now about the self keyword is that it is used to call the static methods, but here the createNode method is non static. Will someone be able to help me out in understanding the context of this statement, what I can say here is the the DomDocument class doesn't have any createNode method at all. Will anyone be able to help? 
Thank you very much.

```
class array2xml extends DomDocument
{
    public $nodeName;
    private $xpath;
    private $root;
    private $node_name;
    public $xml_data;

    public function __construct($root='root', $node_name='node')
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->encoding = "UTF-8";
        $this->formatOutput = true;
        $this->node_name = $node_name;
        $this->root = $this->appendChild($this->createElement($root));
        $this->xpath = new DomXPath($this);
    } 

    public function createNode( $arr, $node = null)
    {   
        if (is_null($node))
        {
            $node = $this->root;
        }
        foreach($arr as $element => $value) 
        {
            $element = is_numeric( $element ) 
                ? $this->node_name 
                : $element;
            $element = htmlspecialchars($element,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
            $child = $this->createElement($element, (is_array($value) 
                ? null 
                : htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')));
            $node->appendChild($child);
            if (is_array($value))
            {
                self::createNode($value, $child);
            }
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $this->xml_data= $this->saveXML();
        return $this->saveXML();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell me that your code really does have indenting...

Comment: Hi Charles yes it has indenting and it is in working order as well there are no error issues with the code at all.

Comment: Hi I have indented it again as this is the first time I have posted a question. Is it not 8 spaces to indent the code ? sorry for me being stupid here.

Comment: You want to know the meaning of statics? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: You are calling a method that was not declared static in a static context. You should be using `$this->createNode($value, $child);` in the above code anyway. Also consider using `createTextNode()` instead of manually escaping with `htmlspecialchars()`, especially if the target is XML rather than HTML.

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Hi Dave and Bondye thank you very much for your help but I am very curious about it as the code works fine. Let me try using $this->createNode. Yeah the statement works fine. By the way when should self be used should it only be used for calling the static methods? is there any other case where we should use it?

Comment: Hi Dave I am using htmlspecialchars() as the array data contains the style info as well as the HTML tags too and the xml file that was generated as a result was invalid.

Comment: @WajidAbbasi Calling non static methods in a static context will "work" but it will raise an `E_STRICT` error - if you didn't see it you should turn your error reporting level up in development. The correct way to call it in the code sample above is to use an instance method and call it with `$this->`.

Comment: @WajidAbbasi If you use explicit text nodes you do not have to worry about escaping entities, DOM handles it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave will certainly do it but thank you again for the $this->createNode($value,$child) hint. BTW when we say static context what does it exactly mean ? Does it mean that (self::static method) is correct but (self::non static method) isn't and must be avoided at all cost?

Comment: @WajidAbbasi In a nutshell, yes. The only reason it works at all is for backwards compat with PHP4, which did not distinguish between static and instance methods. In general if something was not not declared static, you MUST use `->` as an object operator, `::` should only be used on static methods. The only exception to this is `parent::` (because PHP likes being inconsistent). `self::` is basically the static equivalent of `$this` HOWEVER it always refers to the location of declaration of a method. If you want to call an overloaded static method you use `static::` (see late static bindings)

Comment: Thank you Dave I really appreciate your help in this regard. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP `self` **always** refers to the class where `self` was executed. So in your case `self` will refer to a method inside the class `array2xml`.

Usually `self` is used to call `static` methods. Since in your case the method that is called by `self` isn't static, it would have been better to use `$this` instead.

Where `parent` always calls the method from the "parent" class. So the class that is extended. Again in your case when `parent::some function()` is called, it will search for that method in the `DomDocument` class. Because that is the "parent" (extended) class.

The reason that `parent::__construct()` is called in the constructor of the `array2xml` class, is because the constructor of the extended class is **never** called automatically when your own class also uses a `__construct()`. Unless your class does **not** have a `__construct()`. Only then PHP will call the `__construct()` of the parent class. Otherwise you'll have to call it manually from your own constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot w00 for your help its of great help.

Comment: w00 when self is called will all the data variable values of the class object remain the same for example in the code will the same value be used if the new object is created of the class with in the same class method?

Comment: @WajidAbbasi Yes, assuming the `variable` is made `static`, then it will be the same for every `instance` of the class. If it is **not** a `static` variable, then each `instance` can have its own value assigned to it.